# Python3 metaclass: use to validate constructor argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I was planning to use metaclass to validate the constructor argument in Python3, but it seems `__new__`method has no access to the variable `val`, because the class `A()` has not been instantiated yet.

Sow what's the correct way to do it?

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, superclasses, attributedict):
        print("clsname: ", clsname)
        print("superclasses: ", superclasses)
        print("attributedict: ", attributedict)
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, superclasses, attributedict)

class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

A(123)
```

Comment: Does it have to be a metaclass? Could it be a parent class instead? Or maybe a decorator?

Comment: Just make sure only string value are allowed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I know I can do it with a parent class or decorator, but I want to try to use it with a metaclass.

Comment: You want `A().val` to only allow strings?  Better tool for the job is descriptors, not metaclasses.

Comment: @wim Agree with you, but I want to see can I do it with a metaclass?

Comment: @wim Just for feature researching in Python

Comment: For "feature researching" about metaclasses, go through the excellent answer of e-satis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/674039).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wim is absolutely correct that this isn't a good use of metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455904/1222951), but it's certainly *possible* (and easy, too).

Consider how you would create a new instance of your class. You do this:

```
A(123)
```

In other words: You create an instance by calling the class. And python allows us to create custom callable objects by defining a [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__). So all we have to do is to implement a suitable `__call__` method in our metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, str):
            raise TypeError('val must be a string')

        return super().__call__(val)

class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

And that's it. Simple, right?

```
>>> A('foo')
<__main__.A object at 0x007886B0>
>>> A(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "untitled.py", line 5, in __call__
    raise TypeError('val must be a string')
TypeError: val must be a string
```

Comment: –1 this does not prevent later assignment of a non-string to the attribute val.

Comment: this could work with dataclasses module which allows to "freeze" object after instantiation - still vim is right that's not the way python works :)

Answer (score 4):

> ... it seems __new__method has no access to the variable val, because the class A() has not been instantiated yet.

Exactly.

> So what's the correct way to do it?

Not with a metaclass.

Metaclasses are for fiddling with the creation of the class object itself, and what you want to do is related to *instances* of the class.

**Best practice:** don't type-check the `val` at all.  Pythonic code is [duck-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  Simply document that you expect a string-like argument, and users who put garbage in get garbage out.